# PHP - Execute javascript and redirect to a new page after successful login

Tags: javascript, php

I have this `login.php` and a javascript to sync the date and time from the client browser to the server of my openwrt router. What I want is, every time a user successfully logs in, it'll execute that javascript and then redirect to `status.php` which is the home page. Here's what I've tried so far

```
if ($_POST['username'] == $user[0] && $_POST['password'] == $pass[0]) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        echo '<script src="date.js"></script>';
        header("Location: status.php");
        exit;
    }
```

But it gives me this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /www/login.php:10) in /www/login.php on line 11

How do I fix it ?

Some of you may think my question is a duplicate but please understand that I need to execute that javascript after successful login.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot send the header after echoing. To solve this, [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) is used to turn output buffering on which means when using `echo`, no output is sent but instead it is stored in an internal buffer and when we call [ob_end_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) after we have called [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), the internal buffer contents will be flushed and output buffering will stop.

Try:

```
ob_start();
echo '<script src="date.js"></script>';
header("Refresh: 5; url=status.php");
ob_end_flush();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that but the javascript doesn't get executed. It just gets me straight to `status.php` without syncing the date and time.

Comment: @hillz Okay you can refresh after like 5 second to give time to js to execute. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can't put header.. after "echo .." or other html element ..

why you need to put your date.js ?

```
if ($_POST['username'] == $user[0] && $_POST['password'] == $pass[0]) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
 //   echo '<script src="date.js"></script>';
    header("Location: status.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I need to sync the date and time after successful login, so commenting out that `js` is out of question

Comment: Well, it won't run anyway, so commenting it out makes no difference.

Comment: You can do it in PHP .. with time();

Answer (score 0):

put you JavaScript code out side your php code , open your php code and before your JavaScript code close the php put your JavaScript code normally without echo after that put the begin and end tags for php